# Past verb + んじゃない what is his function?

Tags: negation

兄貴は夢を叶えたんじゃない

Which I think it's like "My brother didn't fulfill his wish"

What difference is from 兄貴は夢を叶えなかった

?

Edit the whole sentence is:

お兄さんは"夢"を"約束"に変えてくれた.
兄貴は夢を叶えたんじゃない.
約束を守ってくれたんだ!

Comment: We need context, because 叶えたんじゃない can mean 1) [かなえたんじゃない]{LHLLLLLLH} "You made your dream come true, right?" 2) [かなえたんじゃない]{LHLLLLLHL} "It's not that you made your dream come true"

Comment: @Chocolate Given that OP is trying to see the difference between both sentences, I am pretty sure it's the latter because the meaning is much closer to 兄貴は夢を叶えなかった

Comment: Yes, from context I can tell his dreamdidn't come true

Comment: If you *do* have more context, [it might be a better idea to update your question including all the available context](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2189/what-should-i-do-if-i-was-asked-for-the-context-why-is-it-important) rather than just setting a bounty. After all, Chocolateさん who is a native speaker and is probably much more qualified to address your answer than I am, **asked for context in their first comment**, but it looks like you overlooked it.

Comment: Oh sorry I thought my answer got to him.

I'm fairly sure from context he is saying that his brother dream didn't come true
 @Chocolate

Comment: @Blueshell sorry, by adding context I am not asking if you are sure of what 兄貴 is saying, but if you can provide the full paragraph or the full text you found your sentence in, or the full scene if it's from a movie, drama, etc.

Comment: It's from a manga.

The whole sentence would be...


お兄さんは"夢"を"約束"に変えてくれた.

兄貴は夢を叶えたんじゃない.

約束を守ってくれたんだ!

Comment: Learners sometimes misunderstand the surrounding context and their misunderstandings then make answering more difficult. In order to avoid that situation, it's always best to provide the context unaltered than trying to decipher it and deliver that.

Comment: I see. I posted the whole sentence in the opeining! Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

兄貴は夢を叶えたんじゃない (in this context) means *it is not that my brother made the dream come true / my brother not only made the dream come true*.

兄貴は夢を叶えなかった means simply *my brother did not make the dream come true*.

The speaker is saying that the brother made something happen and it wasn't a dream but a promise. んじゃない（のではない） negates the clause as whole whereas a simple negation negates the verb (叶える) and means it did not happen.

I think it is similar to English *it's not that A* and the simple negation of A. (*It's not that he did something wrong* is not the same as *he did nothing wrong* in a nuanced manner, perhaps depending on contexts.)